# 64-bit ALU outputs are showing high impedance on TestBench waves

Tags: verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

I have to make a 64 Bit ALU that takes in A and B 64-bit inputs, a carry_in input and outputs a 64bit result along with a 1-bit carry_out. There is also a 5 bit function-select FS. Where FS[0] controls whether B is inverted or not (using a 2to1 mux.) F[1] does the same for the A. And FS[4:2] determines which operation (Adding, subtracting, logical operations, etc) using an 8to1 Mux. Below is the code for the ALU and Testbench.

I'm pretty sure my testbench is good and so is all the separate components for the ALU. I'm not too confident about my top-level where I instantiate and connect all the inputs/outputs. What is causing the high impedance in the waveform?

```
module ALU(A, B, FS, cin, cout, result); 
input [63:0] A, B;
input [4:0] FS;
input cin;
output cout;
output  [63:0] result;


eight_one_mux u7 (firstoutA & secoutB, firstoutA | secoutB, sum, firstoutA ^ secoutB,
left, right, 1'b0, 1'b0, FS[4:2], result);

adder u6 (firstoutA, secoutB, cin, sum, cout);

firstmux u1 (A, !A, FS[1], firstoutA);

secmux u2 (B, !B, FS[0], secoutB);

Alu_shifter u5 (A, left, right);


endmodule 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//These are the two muxes to split into input and inverted input A,B
module firstmux(a, nota, firstS, firstoutA);
input [63:0] a, nota;
input firstS;
output reg [63:0] firstoutA;

always @(a or nota or firstS) 

begin

case(firstS)

0 : firstoutA = a;
1 : firstoutA = nota; 
default : firstoutA = 1'bx;

endcase
end

endmodule
//<><><><><><><>//
module secmux(b, notb, secS, secoutB);
input [63:0] b, notb;
input secS;
output reg [63:0] secoutB;

always @(b or notb or secS) 

begin

case(secS)

0 : secoutB = b;
1 : secoutB = notb; 
default : secoutB = 1'bx;

endcase
end

endmodule
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


//This is the Shifter Blocks
module Alu_shifter (shiftA, right, left); //This shifter block shifts the A input once right or left
  input [63:0] shiftA;
  output [63:0] right;
  output [63:0] left;
  
  shift_right w1 (    //instantiate right shifter block
  .a_R(shiftA),  
  .R(right)
  );
  
  shift_left w2 (   //instantiate left shifter block
  .a_L(shiftA),
   .L(left)
  );
  
endmodule
////////><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><///////
module shift_right (a_R, R); // right shifter block
input [63:0] a_R;
output [63:0] R;
assign R = a_R >> 1;  //shift A right once (shift in a 0)
 endmodule


module shift_left (a_L, L);  //left shifter block
input [63:0] a_L;
output [63:0] L;
assign L = a_L << 1; //shift A left once (shift in a 0)
endmodule
//End shifter blocks (3 total modules)
//----------------------------------------------------//////////////////////
//This is the Adder that Adds A, B and cin
module adder(addA, addB, nic, sum, cout);
input [63:0] addA, addB;
input nic;
output [63:0] sum;
output cout;

assign {cout, sum} = addA + addB + nic;


endmodule

//----------------------------------------------------//////////////////////
//This is the 8to1 Mux that decides which operation is put forward
module eight_one_mux(D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, S, out);
input [63:0] D0, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7;
input [2:0] S;
output reg [63:0] out;

always @(D0 or D1 or D2 or D3 or D4 or D5 or D6 or D7 or S) 

begin

case(S)

0 : out = D0; //And
1 : out = D1; //Or
2 : out = D2; //Adder
3 : out = D3; //xor
4 : out = D4; //lefter
5 : out = D5; //righter
6 : out = D6; //GND
7 : out = D7; //GND
default : out = 1'bx;

endcase
end

endmodule
////////////-------------------------------////////////////////////////////
```

````
module ALU_tb();

reg [63:0] A, B;
reg [4:0] FS;
reg cin;

wire cout;
wire [63:0] result;


     
     ALU dut (
     .A(A),
     .B(B),
     .FS(FS),
     .cin(cin),
     .cout(cout),
     .result(result)
                    );


initial begin
A = 8'b11001100;
B = 8'b11001101;
FS = 5'b01101;
cin = 1;
end

always
#5 cin <= ~cin;

always begin
#5
A <= A + 1;
B <= B + 2;
#5;
end

initial begin
#100 $finish;
end
endmodule
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to define signals (`wire`) for connections between modules. For example, you have `left` and `right` as outputs of `Alu_shifter` module and they are connected to `firstmux` and `secmux` modules; however, they are not defined in your top module. You should add following signal definitions to your topmodule:

```
wire [63:0] left,right;
wire [63:0] firstoutA;
wire [63:0] secoutB;
wire [63:0] sum;
```

Also, `eight_one_mux` module takes eight 64-bit inputs. However, you set the last two of them as `1'b0`. You should change them to `64'b0` as below.

```
eight_one_mux u7 (firstoutA & secoutB, firstoutA | secoutB, sum, firstoutA ^ secoutB,
left, right, 64'b0, 64'b0, FS[4:2], result);
```

Finally, `!A` does not invert all bits of `A` (same for `B`). It applies a reduction operation and generates a 1-bit signal (and `firstmux` module expects a 64-bit signal in its second input port).

Answer (score 2):

Unexpected high impedance (`z`) values are typically the result of undriven signals, and that is the problem with your code.

```
adder u6 (firstoutA, secoutB, cin, sum, cout);
```

In the line above, you connect the 1-bit signal `firstoutA` to the 64-bit `addA` input port.  This connects `firstoutA` to `addA[0]`, leaving the other 63 bits undriven.  Thus, `addA[63:1]` are all `z`.

`firstoutA` is a 1-bit signal because you did not explicitly declare it.  Also, undeclared signals are assumed to be of type `wire`, which default to `z`.
It is good practice to declare all signals.

To find all undeclared signals, add this to the top of your code:

```
`default_nettype none
```

You should get compile errors like:

```
Error-[IND] Identifier not declared
  Identifier 'firstoutA' has not been declared yet. If this error is not 
  expected, please check if you have set `default_nettype to none.

Error-[IND] Identifier not declared
  Identifier 'secoutB' has not been declared yet. If this error is not 
  expected, please check if you have set `default_nettype to none.
```